# Add wildcard in join condition

Tags: mysql, select, join, wildcard, sql-like

How do I add wildcards % to the "specifications.sn" ?

```
SELECT `products2`.`type`, 
       `products2`.`sn`, 
       `products2`.`lap`, 
       `specifications`.`year` 
FROM `products2`
INNER JOIN `specifications` 
      ON `products2`.`sn` LIKE `specifications`.`sn`
WHERE `products2`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1
```

EDIT:

Added current query

- Removed backticks
- Added your CONCAT

  ```
  SELECT products2.type, 
  products2.sn, 
  products2.lap, 
  specifications.year 
  FROM products2
  INNER JOIN specifications 
  ON products2.sn LIKE CONCAT('%', specifications.sn, '%')
  WHERE products2.id = ? LIMIT 1
  ```

Alternative query - Same error like code above

- Removed backticks
- Removed INNER JOIN
- Added LIKE in WHERE statement

  ```
  SELECT products2.type, 
  products2.sn, 
  products2.lap, 
  specifications.year
  FROM products2, 
  specifications
  WHERE products2.id = ? AND products2.sn LIKE '%' + specifications.sn + '%' LIMIT 1
  ```

EDIT2

PHP code

```
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT products2.type, 
products2.sn, 
products2.lap, 
specifications.year 
FROM products2
INNER JOIN specifications 
ON products2.sn LIKE CONCAT('%', specifications.sn, '%')
WHERE products2.id = ? LIMIT 1')) { 

$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$id = $_GET['id'];
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($type, $sn, $lap, $year);
$stmt->fetch();

echo $type . '<br/>';
echo $sn . '<br/>';
echo $lap . '<br/>';
echo $year . '<br/>';

$stmt->close();

} else {
echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

Comment: I think it's a problem of how the query is called. If you paste it in phpmyadmin it will work

Comment: You're right. How can I fix this problem?
Is it because i'm using prepared statement?

Comment: Could you post the php part as well please?

Comment: you have to escape the quotes inside the query: \' \'

Comment: also, you are binding the 'i' parameter, while in the query you are using '?' is that normal? On a second note, please note that you are getting the value of $id AFTER binding it. I would retrieve it before hand.

Comment: Like this: LIKE \'%\' + specifications.sn + \'%\'

Comment: Yes, the parameter with 'i' and ? is normal. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
I will retrieve the $id before then.

Comment: yes, should be like this. If you're not sure of the query you can echo the compiled query to the browser

Comment: Now I get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '+ specifications.sn + '%' LIMIT 1' at line 2

Comment: It works! Added the \'%\' as you said. But I used the "current query" / Code #2 in my question above. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT `products2`.`type`,
       `products2`.`sn`,
        `products2`.`lap`, `specifications`.`year`
FROM `products2`
INNER JOIN `specifications`
      ON `products2`.`sn` LIKE 
         CONCAT(`specifications`.`sn`, '%')
WHERE `products2`.`id` = ? LIMIT 1
```

Please note the following:

- this is going to be highly ineffective regarding to join performances
- `CONCAT(NULL, 'ADADSA')` returns `NULL`, therefore you have to take care of this special use case if you think `specifications`.`sn` might be NULL.

Cheers.

Comment: Is your like %`specifications`.`sn`% ?

Comment: you can use CONCAT with as many parameters as you wish, for instance in your case you can indeed do `CONCAT('%', specifications.sn, '%')`

Comment: You note that it's ineffective.
How would you compare two columns in two different tables?

Comment: well this is ineffective however you might not have any other easy solution to achieve your objective. I don't know why you have this error.

Comment: I think it looks like it's trying to dividing whith the percent sign.

Comment: would you mind posting your final query please? In your the question?

Comment: @user1273409 you have to escape the quotes in your `$mysqli->prepare('')` statement.